# Can I write a function that detect if it is called from 'with'-statement or not?

Tags: python, with-statement

More specifically, can I detect if a function is called as `EXPR` in `with EXPR: BLOCK` statement?
I am trying to make myself familiar with the usage of `with`-statement in python.  As a first step, I re-implemented an example, which generate marked up text, appeared in [the reference](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) of `contextlib.contextmanager` (ignoring exception handling for now).

```
class Markup(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tags = []
        self.append = self.tags.append
        self.pop = self.tags.pop

    def tag(self, name):
        self.append(name)
        return self

    def __enter__(self):
        print('<{}>'.format(self.tags[-1]))

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('</{}>'.format(self.pop()))

>>> m = Markup()
>>> with m.tag('ELEMENT'):
...     print('sample text')
...
<ELEMENT>
sample text
</ELEMENT>
```

This works as expected. Then, I got to think if `tag()` can also generate empty elements:

```
>>> m = Markup()

# if a function appears as EXPR of "with EXPR: BLOCK", 'ELEMENT' is a container element. .
>>> with m.tag('ELEMENT'):
...     print('sample text')
...
<ELEMENT>
sample text
</ELEMENT> 

# in other cases, ELEMENT is an empty element.
>>> m.tag('ELEMENT')
<ELEMENT/>
```

To my naive eyes, it seems doable if callee can detect if it is called from `with`-statement or not. However, I do not know if this detection is possible or not. Is there such a way and, if there is, how?

Comment: Note that the documentation says "This is not recommended as a real way of generating HTML!" Maybe this is just a hypothetical example, but if not, then please don't do this. :)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me the warning. Yes, I was aware of it, and this question is hypothetical. If the answer (by Amber and also found PEP 0343, which I should've read before asking) is otherwise, I might have pursued a bit more to make this construct work. Alas it was no to be. So don't worry, this failed pursuit is safely locked up in my head :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually calling `tag()` "from" the `with` statement. You're calling `tag()`, then passing the return value from `tag()` to the `with` statement, which then calls `__enter__` on that passed-in value, then runs the body, then calls `__exit__`.

So no, you can't detect the `with` statement before it's actually invoked (which is after `tag()` is called).

Comment: Thank you for a concise answer.  Although your answer is not what I want to hear, this saves me from chasing shadows:)